# Brightness is too much and I can't control it

Tags: brightness

I have installed brightness indicator, but there is no benefit as there is an error popping out: `no backlights were found on your system`. I am using a desktop. And the brightness and lock setting is also not showing any brightness bar. Please help me. It's straining my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a desktop, it is usually not possible for Ubuntu to change the brightness. You have to use the brightness buttons on your monitor.

Comment: Brightness buttons on my monitor are not working. Is there any way to do it by command line.

Comment: With desktop computers it is not possible for the computer to change the monitor's brightness. It can only send it's graphical output to the monitor.  Laptops have an extra connection to the monitor through which they can change the brightness. You will have to get your monitor's brightness buttons repaired if you want to change the brightness.